# how to convert yearmon to numbers indicating the order of date

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a column that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Iu7P.png)

I want to create another column that indicates 'April 2018' is '1', 'May 2018' is '2'. I tried to use rank(), but I only got this:

```
data$'X1'<-rank(as.numeric(as.Date(data$MONTH)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jj7S.png)

Comment: use `as.integer(as.factor(df$MONTH))`

Answer (score 0):

Package *lubridate* has a lot of convenience functions for handling dates. In your case:

```
library(lubridate)
the_date  <- 'April 2018'
paste(the_date, 'is month number',
      month(my(the_date))
      )
```

Note that the function name `my` is short for **m**onth and **y**ear, following lubridate's mnemonic function naming.